# Recently accessed file list

Tags: windows

When ever I open many files, they always show up in Start->Documents.

I can clear this by going right click start->properties->start menu->customize->clear documents.

Is there any other way to do this, like with command line, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Ccleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/)** does that (with a right click on the Recycle Bin > Run CCleaner) when **Recent Documents** is checked under **Windows Explorer**.

*Ccleaner is freeware (i recommend downloading the [Slim](http://www.ccleaner.com/download/builds) version, it does not include the browser search bar). a portable version is also available.*

or disable the recording of recently opened documents altogether:

```
User Key: [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
System Key: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\
Explorer]
Value Name: NoRecentDocsHistory
Data Type: REG_DWORD (DWORD Value)
Value Data: (0 = disable restriction, 1 = enable restriction)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I would like to know how to do this by programming it, but i'll ask it on stackoverflow